# Enabling localization in ASP.NET, Razor, javascript, dhtmlx or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, razor-2

How do you go about enabling Globalization and Localization in ASP.NET, MVC, Razor, javascript and dhtmlx? I have been looking around for answers and all references I found used the Globalization.js library from jquery. Does anybody have example code using dhtmlx or pure javascript instead? I know how to reference resources within the .cshtml files (Razor) with @using Resources, but how do you reference these resources, like @Resources.UserID, within javascripts embeded within cshtml? I am talking about scripts like ~/Scripts/Global.js.

When I put this in web.config under system.web, create a resources.de.resx file and add de-DE to languages in IE, the title changes as expected using below code, my problem is referencing this in javascripts, so I can change text on forms etc.

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

login.cshtml:

```
@using SquishIt.Framework
@using SquishIt.Mvc
@using Resources 
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>@Resources.Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/favicon.ico")" />
    @(Bundle.Css()
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxLayout/codebase/dhtmlxlayout.css")
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxLayout/codebase/skins/dhtmlxlayout_dhx_skyblue.css")
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxwindows.css")
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/skins/dhtmlxwindows_dhx_skyblue.css")
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxForm/codebase/skins/dhtmlxform_dhx_skyblue.css")
          .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxForm/codebase/skins/dhtmlxform_dhx_skyblue_custom.css")
          .Add("~/Content/Site.css")
          .MvcRender("~/Content/SquishIt/BaseLogon_#.css"))
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <!-- Empty on purpose, JavaScript populates HTML -->
    <!-- Text ruler used to measure text from JavaScript -->
    <span id="TextRuler" class="TextRuler"></span>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var SKIN_NAME          = "dhx_skyblue";

    var URL_WINDOWS_IMAGES = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/imgs/")";
    var URL_LOGIN_FORM     = "@Url.Content("~/XML/Forms/Base/Logon.xml")";
    var URL_LOGIN          = "@Url.Content("~/Base/Login/")";
    var URL_MAIN           = "@Url.Content("~/Base/Main/")";

    var LOGON_SESSION_ID   = "@(Session["LOGON_SESSION_ID"])";
    var LOGOFF_MESSAGE     = "@(ViewData.ContainsKey("LogOffMessage") ? ViewData["LogOffMessage"] : "")";
</script>
@(Bundle.JavaScript()
      .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxLayout/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxLayout/codebase/dhtmlxlayout.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxLayout/codebase/dhtmlxcontainer.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxwindows.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/dhtmlx/dhtmlxForm/codebase/dhtmlxform.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Global.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Utility/Browser.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Utility/XML.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Utility/ErrorHandler.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Utility/Form.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Utility/MessageBox.js")
      .Add("~/Scripts/Base/Logon.js")
    .MvcRender("~/Content/SquishIt/BaseLogon_#.js"))
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post, it offers an alternative way that i have implemented on my web app..

http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx

You will have to create an HTTML handler that will translate your js files according to specific tags.

There is also some configuration required for the routing engine of mvc.
This code should go in your global.asax.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //This will send .axd filse to the custom translate handler
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{folder}/{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

NOTE! If you use ISS 7 then you should register the handler like this:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ScriptTranslatorHandler" path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Use `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"` to support backward comparability and add the previously known HTTP handler element.

```
  <system.web>
     <httpHandlers>
          <add path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />
          <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks (eller skulle jeg sige tak? :) I tried your example, however could not get it to work. I added the handler as *.js since I got a ton of javascripts that eventually needs to have translations and they all end in .js, when I try referring to Translate(something) in a javascript, I get: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Translate' is undefined. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: your not missing anything that means that the HTTP handler is not running... because it had to relapse the `"Translate(ResourceKey)"` to the actual string from the resource file.. see if called to your script using `myScript.js.axd` its important to include the AXD suffixe so that IIS will know that it needs to run your custom handler.

Comment: I change this in login.cshtml .Add("~/Scripts/Base/Logon.js.axd") and I have this in web.config     <httpHandlers> <add verb="*" path="*.js.axd" type="TiPSViewWeb.ScriptTranslator" />    </httpHandlers> since ScriptTranslator is under namespace TiPSViewWeb. I get <data>
    <action type="notfounderror" message="The URL requested was not valid (item not found)." />
</data> for logon.js.axd and no form shows up

Comment: Your problem is probably here `<httpHandlers> <add verb="" path=".js.axd" type="TiPSViewWeb.ScriptTranslator" /> </httpHandlers>` The handler is not register in the IIS for some reason.. What ISS Version are you using ? see edited answer for IIS 7

Comment: I believe it's IIS 7.5, given that I'm running w7 prof, gives same result on win server 2008 R2

Comment: VS is complaining about this <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /> and will not start webpage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25033/discussion-between-mortalus-and-aggaton)

Comment: Thanks Mortalus for the chat, however still no resolution.

Comment: Of course !!! ... there is also some configuration to the routing engine of MVC .. try this code in your gloabl asax: `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{folder}/{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");`

Comment: I put the above lines in RegisterRoutes in global.asax, no difference, still says "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Translate' is undefined"

Comment: For clarification, I am trying to call Translate from within the logon.js script. I have inserted this <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Base/logon.js.axd"></script> above the regular javascript section after <body

Comment: The logon.js is added within a @(Bundle.JavaScript() section as .Add("~/Scripts/Base/Logon.js") after the <script

Comment: Alright, I got a little further, turned out I needed to restart the AppPool for the routing add to kick in since it was put in Application_Start(), the handler now fires when I put logon.js.axd in the .Add statement, however when ReadFile is called in ProcessRequest, it complains about all the dhtmlx stuff, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'dhtmlXForm' is undefined". It's like the scope of logon.cshtml is lost.

Comment: I cleared cleaned and recompiled from scratch, cleared the cache and rebooted the system, and now everything seem to work. When I put this in the init for the form this.setItemText("UserID", "Translate(UserID)"); I get german text for that label, after changed the browsers language. Very nice, thanks a bunch Mads. Not really sure which step it was that solved the issues.

Comment: To clarify for others in need of this solution, I do .Add("~/Scripts/Base/Logon.js.axd") for each module I have translation in, and each string is specified as "Translate(UserID)", where UserID match up with a string in the Resources.